# How can i create a function with two-dimensional arrays and adding elements in the same position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I would like to know how to write a function that has two parameters of two-dimensional arrays assuming the two arrays have the same number of rows and the same number of columns, the function adds the two arrays by adding elements in the same position and returns the new array. 
for Example c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j] for the i'th row and j'th column elements.

help is much appreciated.

Comment: Step 1. `function func_name() { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uff.. Your solution. View a demo of it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/3MYGg/2/)**

```
//----Declarations-------------
var xArray1 = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2]
];

var xArray2 = [
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2]
];

var xResultArray = [];
//-----Declarations-------------

//---Function definition-------------------
function fillNewArray(xA1, xA2) {   
    for(var i = 0; i < xA1.length; i++) {            
        var xNew = [];            
        for(var j = 0; j < xA1[i].length; j++) {
           xNew[xNew.length] = xA1[i][j] + xA2[i][j];                       
        }            
        xResultArray[xResultArray.length] = xNew;
    }    
    alert(JSON.stringify(xResultArray));        
}
//---Function definition-------------------

//---Function call--------------
fillNewArray(xArray1,xArray2);
//---Function call--------------
```

Comment: @user2995331 Glad to help.! Try to consider this as an accepted answer. :)